# PCI DSS compliance for paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is there any PCI DSS compliance when implementing paypal in e-commerce website

Note: There is no credit card number store in the website. All of the paypal login details and credit card number is done through the paypal checkout website

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask the PCI Security Standards Council about compliance

Comment: @Mike W though its not a pure programming question, in paypal you can code in such a way so you can implement PCI , for example Transparent direct feature in Payflow PRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If payment done via paypal checkout website, paypal takes care of PCI compliance. You only need to be PCI compliant if you log the Credit card information on your website.

So, in general if the buyer enters the credit card information on any PayPal checkout Page,
you do not require PCI as PayPal takes care of PCI.

If you implement Payment Gateway that buyer enters the Credit card information on your website directly, then you will need to implement PCI from [here](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/pci_compliant_solution)